# Angular js : Empty space coming for dropdown in IE 10

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down which is populated using ng-repeat as below(with dummy values) :

```
<select ng-model="methodId" name="methodName" id="method" >
<option ng-repeat="detail in details" value="{{detail.modeId}}" ng-  selected="detail.modeId == a.modeId">  {{detail.description}}  </option>
</select>
```

On clicking the drop down, an empty row is also populated along with other values

Solutions tried : 
1)To add an extra option.

```
<option value="" ng-hide="true"></option>
```

This works in chrome, but not in IE

2)To initialize the ng-model.
This works in most of the cases. But there is a scenario in our project where we cant initialize the ng-model value all the time(as it is dependent on few other factors)

Is there any other solution for this problem. Kindly provide your suggestions. Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Add your items of the model in your question body please.

Comment: This is happening irrespective of the structure of the model value : {"AE","AK","AL","AP","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","FL"}     or even if it is an array of objects

Comment: Sorry. My bad! I meant ng-repeat

Comment: Ok, then switch to [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). Don't build selects with `ngRepeat`.

Comment: We had few manipulations to do with the value being displayed in drop down. That is why we decided to go with ng-repeat (few customer filters and date filter needs to be applied)

Comment: @Pavi That shouldn't really be a problem. You can do all sorts of things with `ngOptions`. Even string-concatenation right inside the expression. If you can provide more code, I'm sure there is a way to use standard ngOptions.

Comment: I will try to move all the manipulations to a function and will try to use that in ng-options. Will let you know if it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yoshi : tried with ng-options, still the empty space is coming in IE 10.                                                                                                {"details":[{"description":"sdsd","shipModeId":"111","carrier":"sdsd","serviceCode":"sdsd","estArrivalDate":"20140904","estArrivalDays":"1","type":"sds"}]}



<select ng-model="methodId" name="methodName" id="method" ng-options="detail.shipModeId as formatModeForDrpDwn(detail) for detail in details" ng-init="methodId = details[0].shipModeId"></select>

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem in IE 10 (emulated) http://jsbin.com/kinumahipuce/1/.

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi for your time! Appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60384/discussion-between-yoshi-and-pavi).